# Manifolds: TOP $\supseteq$ TRI $\supseteq$ PL $\supseteq$ DIFF?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let me denote the following

- (TOP) topological manifolds
- (PDIFF), for piecewise differentiable
- (PL) piecewise-smooth manifolds
- (DIFF) the smooth manifolds
- (TRI) triangulable manifolds

Is it true that

> (1) TOP $\supseteq$ TRI ?
>
> Namely, every TRI must be TOP manifolds?
>
> (2) TRI $\supseteq$ PL ?
>
> Namely, every PL must be TRI manifolds?
>
> (3) TRI $\supseteq$ DIFF ?
>
> Namely, every DIFF must be TRI manifolds?
>
> (4) PL $\supseteq$ DIFF ?
>
> Namely, every DIFF must be PL manifolds?
>
> (5) So in a short summary, is it true that
>
> $$\text{ TOP $\supseteq$ TRI $\supseteq$ PL $\supseteq$ DIFF} ?$$
>
> How to think these categories of manifolds in terms of **categories** (or **sets** with whose objects are manifolds)? What are their intersections, unions and complements?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by thinking in terms of sets. The answer pretty much depend on your definition of manifolds.

Comment: i.e. categories of manifolds in terms of **categories** (or **sets** with whose objects are manifolds)?

Comment: What is your definition of manifolds?

Comment: I guessed annie heart she meant that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold

Comment: @user170039 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDIFF

Comment: @wonderich: I thought so too. But note that there are variety of definitions that goes by the name "manifold" as noted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Mathematical_definition).

Comment: @all, if you guys have an answer - it will be nice to answer directly. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, these inclusions are all true.

1) is true because "manifold" and "topological manifold" are actually synonyms.

2) is true by an almost obvious construction: very roughly speaking, a locally finite covering by charts in the given PL atlas can be triangulated one chart at a time.

4) is true by [a theorem of Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)#Explicit_methods_of_triangulation).

3) follows from 2) and 4).

Comment: thanks, vote up, a more advanced question is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335386